# How to turn find velocity dispersion from radial velocity

Tags: gravity, orbital-mechanics, mass

[image]

In the above given picture Vi is the velocity of the i-th galaxy in the cluster while Vm is the mean velocity of a galaxy in the cluster. and V i,r is the radial velocity of the i-th galaxy and V m,r is the mean radial velocity. How does converting mean velocity to mean radial velocity introduce a coefficient of 3.

Image source IOAA 2019 question 13.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key assumption is that orbital velocity vectors are distributed randomly. Then the dispersion of velocities along each axis must be the same, e.g. $\sigma_x=\sigma_y=\sigma_z$ if $x$, $y$, and $z$ denote perpendicular axes. But then the total squared velocity dispersion is $\sigma^2=\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2+\sigma_z^2=3\sigma_x^2$.